# Asp.net Core Authorize user with Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to authorize an user with a bearer token send from the request header.
I added this code in startup file of resource server.

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
   auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()                        
  .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

Here is my method in controller.

```
[Authorize("Bearer")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("list")]
public IEnumerable<Products> List()
{
    string Authorization = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
}
```

Application showing me error 401 Unauthorized even if i had token

I am sending this Token in the header request

Authorization:Bearer "xyz"

Comment: have you tried without using policy ? if it works without you might missing something in JWT & Policy configuration

Comment: No it doesn't work.
i forgot to mention that i have two projects 1 is resource server and 2nd is auth server, the authorize attribute works in Auth server but doesn't work in resource server, and the above code is in resource server.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Bearer token you have to add the following code on your Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.Audience = "OAuth:Audience";
        options.Authority = "OAuth:Authority";
        options.ConfigurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            metadataAddress: options.Authority + ".well-known/openid-configuration",
            configRetriever: new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
            docRetriever: new HttpDocumentRetriever() { RequireHttps = false });
    });
}
```

You will also need a middleware to handle the authorization process.
Have a look at [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) and [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)

Comment: I gone through said article.
Is middleware requred when using two projects??
one is resource project other is Auth project

Comment: You have to use the middleware only on your Auth project